# (Simple) Applescript Code Failing

Tags: applescript

I'm getting the following error message when I run this in my Mac OSX Script Editor:

> error "Can’t set «class 1550» of \"b_PlaceName\" to \"Beijing\"."
>   number -10006 from «class 1550» of "b_PlaceName"

Can you see the error in the code?

```
set strVName to "b_PlaceName"
set strVValue to getKVar(strVName)
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    tell active document
        set variable value of strVName to strVValue
    end tell
end tell
--———————————————————————————————
on getKVar(pstrVName)
    tell application "Keyboard Maestro Engine"
        set strKVValue to value of variable pstrVName
        return strKVValue
    end tell
end getKVar
--———————————————————————————————
```

Comment: The first thing I see is this line...
    `set variable value of strVName to strVValue`
should be something more like ...
    `set strVName to strVValue`

But to be honest, I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish with this code. If you can tell me the purpose of the code above, I might be able to help you out more.

Comment: The `variable` classes of Microsoft Word and Keyboard Maestro Engine are completely different. The main issue is that `b_PlaceName` is a literal string and there is no `variable value` of a literal string.

Comment: The purpose of the code is to allow a variable set inside the Program called Keyboard Maestro to be accessible by a variable (with the same name) inside a Word Macro.  Would appreciate any edits to fix my code.